# Linking Widgets

Tags: carto, widget

I'm new to Carto and would like to display multiple layers of data on the map for the year the user selects from a widget. How would I link the layers so that one click on a year widget will filter out multiple layers to display data for the year selected?

Answer (score 1):

If you understand this example:

https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-interactive-based-filter

I would suggest you focus on line 147.

This updates a "viz" (what you are calling a layer) based on the "category toggle" (what you are calling widget). I believe you could add a second line for example:

```
viz2.filter.blendTo(s.in(s.prop('weather'), weatherCategories));
```

And it would affect not only viz but also viz2 based on the changes to the category toggle change.